# Code sign Error

Tags: iphone, code-signing, sign

I have created a new iPhone application.I have two mach machines. I have created the certificate for running application in iPhone in one mac. Can I use the other mac for running the application in iPhone. But when I try to do so I get an error "Codesign error:Code signing is required for product type "Application" in SDK Device iPhone OS 3.1.2. Please some one help me.

Regards,
krishnan.

Comment: Did my solution help, or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you transferred your credentials to the second Mac?  They are stored in your keychain.

You may need to read up on how Code-signing works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing

Here's an overview:

- Developer creates a Certificate via a Certificate Authority (CA)

  - This certificate is used to 'sign' the binary, providing 'proof' of who created it
- Developer then uses the Certificate to sign the binary (**this is the step you're missing on the second MAC**)

  - This is handled via xcode, assuming you've followed the detailed steps on http://developer.apple.com/iphone
- Clients using the binary can now verify the Certificate against a known CA to ensure the integrity of the build.

Comment: Thank you friend. Earlier I had only one account. Now I have created another user using the Agent account and uploaded a certificate Request and downloaded the certificate from portal and it is working fine. Thank you for u your help. - krishnan.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you are code signing on the target as well when you do the Archive build

Spent hours to figure this out. Actually you need to click on Project --> Build Settings --> click target --> code sign..

THIS IS not apparent